# strip a file from empty lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my file

```
first term    word1_0.1    word2_0.2


second term   another word_0.45    last word_0.89
```

I want my out put to be like this :

```
first term
word1_0.1
word2_0.2
second term
another word_0.45
last word_0.89
```

Here's what I did :

```
with open("education.txt",encoding="utf-8") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        if line.strip():
            for part in line.split("\t"):
                file = open('output.csv','a', encoding='utf-8')
                file.write(("".join(part) + "\n"))
                file.close()
```

Which gives me the following result :

```
   first term
    word1_0.1
    word2_0.2



    second term
    another word_0.45
    last word_0.89
```

I can't seem to strip my final result of those empty lines, Any idea where i went wrong ?

Comment: Did you already check what Python *thinks* is in `line` immediately after `if line.strip():`?

Comment: @usr2564301 it gives me the lines on my file without the empty ones, like this : 

first term    word1_0.1    word2_0.2
second term   another word_0.45    last word_0.89

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip the lines and work on only non empty lines.

`education.txt`:

```
first term  word1_0.1   word2_0.2


second term another word_0.45   last word_0.89
```

`updated_code.py`:

```
with open("education.txt",encoding="utf-8") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        if line.strip()!="":
            for part in line.strip().split("\t"):
                file = open('output.csv','a', encoding='utf-8')
                file.write(("".join(part) + "\n"))
                file.close()
```

`output.csv`:

```
first term
word1_0.1
word2_0.2
second term
another word_0.45
last word_0.89
```

[image: output value in csv format]

Disclaimer: Check if `education.txt` has tab (`\t`) between values.